# Не сохраняется сессия telegram в telethon, Python

Tags: python, telegram, сессия, telethon

При запуске приложения требует ввести телефон и код. Код приходит в сам телеграм, поэтому я авторизован в нем на ПК. После ввода вход в приложении совершается, а при выходе из приложения все активные сессии (в т.ч. на ПК) закрываются и приходится заново авторизироваться вначале на телефоне, потом на ПК и в приложении (хотя файл сессии создается).

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
Как можно избежать подобной ситуации?

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = 11111111
api_hash = "12345567890qwertyuiiopasdfgh"

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()`
```